# Toggle for a div containing another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Been trying to make a button which opens a div containing another html page. I had the button working but the main page was opening with the div shown already, I needed it hidden. After messing it all up I'm stuck on this. The button doesn't work.

html

```
<p>Press the button</p>
<button id="button1" onClick="show()">Show / Hide</button>
<div id="Ahover">
    <object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/"></object>
</div>
```

css

```
#Ahover {
    display:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px ridge blue;
}
object {
    width:760px;
    height:600px;
}
```

js

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
   $('#Ahover').toggle() 
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fembjaxp/1/%60)

Any help, what I'm I doing wrong? And is this even possible.

Thanks, got it working in the end by moving the script into  tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This code:

HTML:

```
<p>Press the button</p><button id="button1">Show / Hide</button>
<div id="Ahover"> 
<object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" >
</object></div>
```

CSS:

```
#Ahover {
display:none;
overflow: hidden;
border:1px ridge blue;
}
object {
width:760px;
height:600px; 
display:inline-block
}
```

JS:

```
$('#button1').on('click',function(e){
 $('#Ahover').toggle();
});
```

Demo is here:

> https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/aaqfykz3/2/

Comment: I get it working on the fiddle. But when I input it into my code it doesn't work for some reason. I loaded the library, link the css sheet, but the button does nothing. https://i.imgur.com/yhqkCb4.jpg here just tried to test it, button doesnt work. Sorry if I'm overlooking something really simple.

Comment: Don't worry, just put the script Tag at the end of body section, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the working demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/x2qjdfwk/
The only change is to remove the show() function from the button as you are already applying the jQuery click event to it.

```html
<p>Press the button</p><button id="button1">Show / Hide</button>
```

And make sure you include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<p>Press the button</p><button id="button1" >Show / Hide</button>
<div id="Ahover"></div>
```

js:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
$('#Ahover').toggle();
 $("#Ahover").html('<object data="http://validator.w3.org/" />');
});
```

css:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
}

object {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/